# How to run a specific AJAX call in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using has_scope to filer to filter jobs in a show.html.erb page. Once the jobs are filtered or not, the user can click on a job title and have the detail displayed on the same page on a partial. I have two functions in show.js.erb working, except that when the user clicks on the job title, the system run both call again and re-initialize the jobs selection. Can I isolate the second call so it does not run both functions ?

I have the two lines working well. 
**show.js.erb**

```
$("#job_indiv").html("<%= j render partial: 'jobs/show', :locals => {:job => @job} %>");
```

(The above function display the individual details of the job)

```
$('#job_menu_left').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('menu_left')) %>')
```

(The above function filters the jobs list)

The **view**:

```
<div class="job_intro_display">
            <%= form_tag job_path, method: 'get', id: "jobs_search" do %>
              <div>
                <% @industries = Job.all.distinct.pluck(:industry) - ["", nil] %>
                Industry:<br>
                <% @industries.each do |industry| %>
                  <div class="btn-filter">
                    <%= check_box_tag "by_industries[]", industry %> <%= industry %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
      </div>

<div id="job_menu_left">
  <%= render 'menu_left' %>
</div>
<div id="job_indiv">
  <%= render 'jobs/show' %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            $.get($('#jobs_search').attr('action'),
                $('#jobs_search').serialize(), null, 'script');
            return false;
        });
        $('#jobs_search').submit(function () {
            $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Each ajax should be able to run separately.

Comment: Hey, does anyone knows  how to do please ?

Comment: Why don't you use two different actions? instead of calling both `.html` on the same show view? you could have the `show` action to set the jobs/show partial and another action `show_menu` or something like that to render the menu and do one or two ajax calls when needed